# Left join times out on linq where right table is empty

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a left join to perform . And take the entire objects from it . However it times out when the item collection is empty on doing .Select (x=>x.object) ;

```
 public Tuple<td_GroupLicense, List<td_UserGroupMap>> ReturnActiveLicenseInfo(int GroupID)
    {
        Tuple<td_GroupLicense, List<td_UserGroupMap>> Tuple;


        #endregion
        var GroupUserLicense = from grp in Context.td_Groups
                               from lic in Context.td_GroupLicenses
                                  .Where(x => grp.IdGroup == x.GroupID && x.GroupID == GroupID)
                               from ugm in Context.td_UserGroupMaps
                                .Where(x => grp.IdGroup == x.GroupID && x.GroupID == GroupID)
                                    .DefaultIfEmpty()
                               select new { GL = lic, UGM = ugm };

        td_GroupLicense License = GroupUserLicense.Select(x => x.GL).Distinct().SingleOrDefault();
        List<td_UserGroupMap> UserMaps = GroupUserLicense.Select(x => x.UGM)
                                        .OfType<td_UserGroupMap>()
                                        .DefaultIfEmpty().ToList();

        Tuple = new Tuple<td_GroupLicense, List<td_UserGroupMap>>(License, UserMaps);
        return Tuple;
    }
```

when I do the join then the line in

```
List<td_UserGroupMap> UserMaps = GroupUserLicense.Select(x => x.UGM)
                                        .OfType<td_UserGroupMap>()
                                        .DefaultIfEmpty().ToList();
```

times out since the collection `UGM` in `GroupUserLicense` is null . It cannot do the operation . I want to put the left join result of License and Usegroupmaps into the corresponding objects . But the Right table is null so the timeout occurs . How to overcome that ? And why is it happening ?

Comment: Calling `.OfType<td_UserGroupMap>()` seems to be unnecessary.

Comment: @Alireza but the problem is UGM is actually null so its not able to select neither convert it tolist()